# Loop within echo

Tags: php, wordpress

I usually code websites in pure HTML/CSS but this I'm tinkering with a WordPress theme and as such, have to get my hands dirty with PHP. I'm not completely familiar with the syntax but I learned a bit through trial and error.

Essentially, I have an array of strings that I want to list in an unordered list, however, all of my code is inside `echo`. How can I get the `foreach` loop to work as intended?

The formatting was bit messed up here on StackOverflow so I'm leaving it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/g52KXECk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the `foreach()` part outside of the `echo`, so end the original `echo`, do the `foreach()` and then continue with a new `echo`.

Change:

```
echo '...<ul>
    '.foreach ($levels as $value) {
        <li>.$value.</li>
    }.'
</ul>...';
```

to

```
echo '...<ul>';                        //end original echo
foreach ($levels as $value) {
    echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';    //echo list items with foreach
}
echo '</ul>...';                       //continue with new echo
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure if I could 'exit' an echo and still have the rest processed correctly.